# IntegrityError at /collection/order/ FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error while adding a new object

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

Hi I was just learning django and trying to create a model form with manaytomany relationship between item and order
below is my code snippet.

```
models.py
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,default="",primary_key=True)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customername = models.CharField(max_length=25,default="")
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item,default="")
    metal = models.ForeignKey(Material,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    place = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    orderdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.customername

forms.py:

from django import forms
from .models import Order, Material, Item
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

views.py:
def ItemSaveorUpdate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request,messages.SUCCESS,"Movie rating submitted succesfully")
    else:
       form = ItemForm()
    return render(request,'addItem.html',{"form":form})
def OrderSaveorUpdate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request,messages.SUCCESS,"Order added succesfully")
            return redirect('material')
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = OrderForm(instance=item)
        form.save()
    else:
        #item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = OrderForm()
    return render(request,'addOrder.html',{"form":form})

Template additem.html:
<form action="{% url 'item' %}" request="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="add">
</form>

urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('item/', views.ItemSaveorUpdate, name="item"),
    path('material/', views.MaterialSaveorUpdate, name="material"),
    path('order/', views.OrderSaveorUpdate, name="order"),
```

I am trying to select multiple items while creating an order and after clicking add it is giving the error IntegrityError at /collection/order/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed. Important to mention that the order is getting added which I can see in admin panel but the items are not getting selected.
Please help to avoid this issue and let me know what I missed here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved by removing default for item fields in Order class in models.py

```
item = models.ManyToManyField(Item,default="")

after removing

item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

Its is working fine now.

Thank you.